# Importing + formatting XML files into Excel

Tags: xml, excel, vba

Good day

I need some help with the following VBA code, I want excel to do the following:

- Open multiple XML files
- Format the files to only reflect certain columns
- Paste all the info in the columns in one sheet underneath each othet

The code also needs to remove the header line in line 1 when combining in the one sheet.

This is what I have so far

```
Sub Combined()

'UpdatebyKutoolsforExcel20151214
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xSWb As Workbook
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xFile As String
    Dim xCount As Long

'added
Dim LastRow As Long 'new line

On Error GoTo ErrHandler
Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder [Kutools for Excel]"

If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
    xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
End If

If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'probleem le by die "usedrange"
'hy moet net begin copy by n sekere plek, en tot n sekere plek
Set xSWb = ThisWorkbook
xCount = 1 'lyntjie waar hy moet paste

xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\*.xml") 'alle file met .xml in folder
Do While xFile <> ""
    Set xWb = Workbooks.OpenXML(xStrPath & "\" & xFile, LoadOption:=xlXmlLoadImportToList)

    'copy van xWb.sheet na ons xSWb.sheet
    LastRow = xWb.Sheets(1).Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row 'new line
    'MsgBox LastRow

    If xCount = 1 Then 'just to copy headers if this is the 1st file (New lines)
     xWb.Sheets(1).Range("A1:BQ1").Copy xSWb.Sheets(1).Cells(xCount, 1)
     xCount = 2
    End If


    'xWb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy xSWb.Sheets(1).Cells(xCount, 1) 'copy in cell 2,1 PROBLEEM HIER
    xWb.Sheets(1).Range("A2:BQ" & LastRow & "").Copy xSWb.Sheets(1).Cells(xCount, 1)

    xWb.Close False

    LastRow = xSWb.Sheets(1).Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row 'new line - kry laaste ryjite van ons huidige werkboek
    xCount = LastRow + 1 'new line
    'xCount = xSWb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count + 2 'update waar hy nou na moet copy
    xFile = Dir()
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

xSWb.Save
Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "no files xml", , "Kutools for Excel"

End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: so what is the problem with this code?

Comment: The problem I have is the files I need this macro to copy does not always have the same amount of column headings, but the columns I need is always there. So I need a macro which will help me to do the following: 1. Open a file, remove the columns which I don't need, the copy the info and paste it in another file. The macro needs to do this for about 20 files in one folder, pasting the information underneath each other.

Comment: to clarify then, there's no problem with the code you posted, but you want someone to write some code for you?